# How to wrap Wicket page rendering in a Spring / Hibernate transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, wicket

My application loads entities from a Hibernate DAO, with OpenSessionInViewFilter to allow rendering.

In some cases I want to make a minor change to a field -

```
Long orderId ...

link = new Link("cancel") {
    @Override public void onClick() {
        Order order = orderDAO.load(orderId);
        order.setCancelledTime(timeSource.getCurrentTime());       
    };
```

but such a change is not persisted, as the OSIV doesn't flush.

It seems a real shame to have to call orderDOA.save(order) in these cases, but I don't want to go as far as changing the FlushMode on the OSIV.

Has anyone found any way of declaring a 'request handling' (such as onClick) as requiring a transaction?

Ideally I suppose the transaction would be started early in the request cycle, and committed by the OSIV, so that all logic and rendering would take place in same transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but they (probably sensibly) focused on solving the problem as I stated it rather than the bigger issue of Wicket causing lots of unrelated transactions. I've created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161743/how-to-use-a-single-transaction-for-a-wicket-spring-page-view to try a different tack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer : I've never actually tried this, but I think it would work.  This also may be a little bit more code than you want to write.  Finally, I'm assuming that your WebApplication subclasses SpringWebApplication.  Are you with me so far?

The plan is to tell Spring that we want to run the statements of you onClick method in a transaction.  In order to do that, we have to do three things.

Step 1 : inject the PlatformTransactionManager into your WebPage:

```
@SpringBean
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;
```

Step 2 : create a static TransactionDefinition in your WebPage that we will later reference:

```
protected static final TransactionDefinition TRANSACTION_DEFINITION;
static {
    TRANSACTION_DEFINITION = new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    ((DefaultTransactionDefinition) TRANSACTION_DEFINITION).setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
}
```

Feel free to change the TransactionDefinition settings and/or move the definition to a shared location as appropriate.  This particular definition instructs Spring to start a new transaction even if there's already one started and to use the maximum transaction isolation level.

Step 3 : add transaction management to the onClick method:

```
link = new Link("cancel") {
    @Override 
    public void onClick() {
        new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager, TRANSACTION_DEFINITION).execute(new TransactionCallback() {
            @Override
            public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                Order order = orderDAO.load(orderId);
                order.setCancelledTime(timeSource.getCurrentTime());      
            }
        }
    } 
};
```

And that should do the trick!

Comment: It sounds plausible. Although arguably more messy than calling dao.saveOrUpdate, I suppose that it has the advantage of running the load() in the same Tx, so that it can't happen that the load() sees an entity that is deleted by the time saveOrUpdate() is called.

Comment: Am I mad in wanting an architecture where the first call that requires a Tx creates it, and it is completed by the OSIV?

Comment: Definitely not the cleanest solution...much easier to call save.  But hey, it should do the trick.

Comment: Ha...yeah.  One might say that. ;)  Why do you want to defer the commit, anyway?

Comment: It isn't deferring the commit so much as wrapping a unit of work in a single Tx - as I mentioned in my first comment. I guess that I probably want to commit before rendering the page, so that I know if there were any issues with the commit, although they will by default end up just spewing a stack trace at the user.

Comment: Thinking this through, I may be better solving this problem with an orderDAO.cancelOrder(orderId) which has a single Tx.

Comment: That sounds like a much better way to go...  If you're not doing this kind of workaround for legacy reasons, you're much better doing it right. :)

Answer (score 4):

I generally prefer to use additional 'service' layer of code that wraps basic DAO
logic and provides transactions via @Transactional. That gives me better separation of presentation vs business logic and is
easier to test.

But since you already use OSIV may be you can just put some AOP interceptor around your code
and have it do flush()?

Comment: I'm big on service layers as well, but there really doesn't seem to be anything to be gained (apart from Tx management) from saying that order.setCancelledTime(timeSource.getCurrentTime()) needs to be delegated to business logic.

Comment: Thinking this through, I may be better solving this problem with an orderDAO.cancelOrder(orderId) which has a single Tx.

Comment: Exactly. Use a service layer. The web layer shouldn't know about the persistence layer's existence!

Comment: Arguably that is what I am trying to achieve by just setting the cancelled time, and the web layer must know enough about the persistence layer to fetch entities, but I take your point.